# gnuplot: showing both center line and error band in a key

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot a data set with it's error band by using the following commands, it creates separate keys for each of them (one for band and one for central line) but I want these keys shown in one key on each other.

please help me

```
set termoption enhanced
set xlabel '{/Symbol \326}s [TeV]' 
set ylabel '{/Symbol s}(PP{/Symbol \256}Htt) [pb]'
set style fill transparent solid 0.2 noborder
set key left nobox
plot [5:16] 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\tth-with-ttPDFs-nQCDscale.dat' using 1:3:4 with filledcurves title 
'uncertainty',     '' using 1:2 with lp lt 1 pt 7 ps 0 lw 2 title 'using FitC'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set key spacing 0
set key left reverse
plot 'data' using 1:3:4 with filledcurves title '   ', \
         '' using 1:2 with lp lt 1 pt 7 ps 0 lw 2 title 'Fit and Uncertainty'
```

[image]

Note that the first title consists of a string of spaces.

Comment: Is the feature documented?

Comment: From "help set key samples": "Key entry lines are single-spaced based on the current font size.
 This can be adjusted by `set key spacing <line-spacing>`."

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately these commands didn't solve my problem, I use 4.6 version of gnuplot in Ubuntu 14.04. Are you using the version 5 of gnuplot?

Comment: Gnuplot version 5 was released more than 5 years ago so yes, it is strongly advised to move on from version 4.  There are many, many improvements. Nevertheless, `set key spacing 0` works in version 4.6 also as tested here (4.6 patchlevel 6 Sept 2014).

Comment: According to your guidance I installed gnuplot 5.2 and then my problem solved. In cases we are using more than one data set, is there any way for defining the position of each key (legend) at our desired point?

Comment: There is no support multiple self-managing keys.  However you can build as many keys as you like line-by-line by appending [x,y] coordinates to the component titles: `plot ... title 'foo' at x1,y0,  ... title 'baz' at x1,y0+delta`.  See on-line example: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/custom_key.html