# How do I add more space using gnuplot yerrorbars when I have a lot of data on my chart?

Tags: gnuplot

I added the `yerrorbars` keyword to show the standard deviation on my chart but because I have a lot of data the plot is not very clear and the std deviation as well. I would like to add more spaces when showing the standard deviation in the same way that is added on the line style using `pi` : `set style line 4 lc rgb '#000000' lt 3 lw 1.5 ps 0.5 pt 3 pi 15`. How would I do that?

```
set label 1 "(a) workload: 50K r/s\npre-agg 77K tuples" at "300",6.5 font "{,10}"
plot t=0 "throughput-vs-latency-50K-8combiners-8reducers-all.csv" u (t==0?(t0=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt),t=1):NaN, timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)-t0):(column(2)/1000):(column(3)/1000) skip 2 notitle with linespoints ls 1 axis x1y1 \
, t=0 "throughput-vs-latency-50K-8combiners-8reducers-all.csv" u (t==0?(t0=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt),t=1):NaN, timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)-t0):(column(4)/1000) skip 2 notitle with linespoints ls 2 axis x1y1 \
, t=0 "throughput-vs-latency-50K-8combiners-8reducers-all.csv" u (t==0?(t0=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt),t=1):NaN, timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)-t0):(column(6)/1000) skip 2 notitle with linespoints ls 3 axis x1y2 \
, t=0 "throughput-vs-latency-50K-8combiners-8reducers-all.csv" u (t==0?(t0=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt),t=1):NaN, timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)-t0):(column(8)/1000):(column(9)/1000) skip 2 notitle with yerrorbars ls 4 axis x1y2 \
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would have to split the curve for that data into two parts.
The first part would draw the lines and points for every point in the data set;
the second part would draw errorbars only for every Nth point. The keyword needed is `every N`.

```
 set errorbars lt -1
 
 plot $DATA using 1:2 with linespoints lt 3 notitle, \
      $DATA every 5 using 1:2:3 with yerrorbars lt 3 title "DATA"
```

[image]

Comment: The plot is not the output of the quoted command, which would put the also blue errorbar in front of the blue data. Also the legend has some further manipulation, I guess like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60602750.

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion: instead of crowded errorbars, why not an "error-shade"?

**Code:**

```
### shaded area as error "bar"
reset session

# create some test data
set table $Data
    plot '+' u 1:(sin($1)):(rand(0)+0.25) w table
unset table

set key invert

plot $Data u 1:($2-$3):($2+$3) with filledcurves lc rgb "light-grey" ti "Error", \
     '' u 1:2 w lp ti "Data"
### end of code#
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For many data points with errorbars, consider `set bar 0`, error bars in the background, and/or transparency. Also point size can be reduced.

```
set samp 2000
set table $Data
    plot '+' u 1:(sin($1)+(rand(0)+0.25)):(rand(0)+0.25) w table
unset table

set bar 0

plot $Data with err lc rgb "grey" ti "Error", \
     '' u 1:2 w p lc "black" pt 6 ti "Data"
```

[image]